# Twitter Bootstrap not formatting as I expected

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to format a page where I have an image, then NEXT to it, a heading... and then under the heading, I want some descriptive text.

I am trying this:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-2">
                <img src="~/images/user_error.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-10">
                <h1>@Model.Heading</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row">
            Hello
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But the image stays on it's own row. How can I get the heading NEXT to the image?

Comment: Bootstrap's [grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) don't include `col-xl-*` (extra large). Did you mean `col-xs-*` (extra small)? Or, do you have these defined yourself?

Comment: Indeed, you spotted the error. Thanks. Meant 'lg'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
```

Here is a jsfiddle for people to see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/692UC/